# text-align option и Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

Доброго времени суток, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли заставить Chrome подчиниться? :)

Везде работает, а **Chrome** почему-то ровняет слева и попросту **игнорирует text-align для тега option**, гугление пользы не принесло... Я никогда не спрашиваю, не попытавшись разобраться самому, конечно, не смертельная проблема, но тем не менее.

PS: Готов рассмотреть варианты javascript решений, конечно, если таковые имеются.

Comment: Пробовали селекту прописывать?

Comment: А может это зависит от Doctype?

Comment: Вы сами подумайту - в FF работает, если бы я не так что-то прописывал бы, то не работало бы нигде, более менее терпимое решение данной проблемы описал внизу<br>Да - это танцы с бубном, но нам веб-разрабам не привыкать :D<br>
Если у кого-то есть варианты получше - с удовольствием ознакомлюсь
<br><br>
На заметку - Chrome не IE, DOCTYPE такой значимости не несет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет необходимости выдумывать костыль на дивах, несмотря на то, что не работает text-align работает padding, соответственно средствами JS можно вычислить padding для центрирования каждого из option элемента.

PS: Спецификация спецификацией, а центрирования добиться можно, ИМХО описаный мною выше вариант лучшее решение данной проблемы. Да и нередко длина option'ов примерно одинаковая, что позволяет просто в стилях подобрать подходящий padding...

Answer (score 0):

Такого свойства для опций нет. Как вариант, сделать нестандартный селект дивами, но это уже страшный костыль.

Comment: Если такого свойства нет, почему же, например в FF все ок? Собственно не суть важна, мне не столь принциписально, просто, так сказать. из спортивного интереса...

Comment: набор допустимых для option стилей сильно ограничен, это спецификация.